Oracle SUBSTR results in longer column?
It seems that SUBSTR can result in a longer column? What's going on here?
CREATE TABLE t (
    long_field VARCHAR2(1024)
);

SELECT
    column_name,
    data_length
FROM
    all_tab_cols
WHERE
    table_name = 'T';




COLUMN_NAME
DATA_LENGTH




LONG_FIELD
1024



INSERT INTO t ( long_field ) VALUES ( 'abcdef' );

CREATE TABLE t2
    AS
        SELECT
            substr(long_field, instr(long_field, 'c') + 1) short_field
        FROM
            t;

SELECT
    column_name,
    data_length
FROM
    all_tab_cols
WHERE
    table_name = 'T2';




COLUMN_NAME
DATA_LENGTH




SHORT_FIELD
4096



I'm on Oracle 18:
select BANNER
from V$VERSION;




BANNER




Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production




SUBSTR returns a VARCHAR2(4000) as that is the maximum length sub-string that could be returned from the function.
Just because your function substr(long_field, instr(long_field, 'c') + 1) returns 'def' doesn't mean that it changes the data-type to have a data-length that is the bounded by the data (i.e. VARCHAR2(3)) as SUBSTR could still (for other data) return a 4000 byte string.
If you want a lower data length then use CAST:
CREATE TABLE t3 AS
  SELECT CAST(
           substr(long_field, instr(long_field, 'c') + 1)
           AS VARCHAR2(10)
         ) short_field
  FROM   t;

Then the data dictionary will contain:



TABLE_NAME
COLUMN_NAME
DATA_LENGTH




T3
SHORT_FIELD
10


T2
SHORT_FIELD
4000



fiddle

But a SUBSTR on a VARCHAR2(1000) should never exceed length 1000. Is there a way for SUBSTR to return something longer than the bounds of the input?

@TianxiangXiong Is your last DATA_LENGTH really 4096, or is it 4000? 4000 is the normal maximum number of bytes for a VARCHAR2 column. If you have 4096, you might be using a database with extended string sizes up to 32,767 bytes. That can complicate the situation, because your VARCHAR2 may actually be stored as a CLOB. You can check your database string configuration with this query: select value from v$parameter where name like 'max_string_size'; And CLOB size might depend on your NLS settings: select * from v$nls_parameters;

@TianxiangXiong A SUBSTR of a 1000 byte string will never return more than 1000 bytes but 1000 bytes will also fit into a VARCHAR2(4000). It is simpler to set the data length to the maximum theoretical length for a SUBSTR than to any length bounded by the actual size of the data (because next time you run the query the data could have changed and you could have a 4000 byte sub-string). The conclusion should be that if you want a specific size of data then supply the value manually rather than trying to automatically generate it.

Yes, I'm using extended string sizes. I'd expect the DB to be smart enough to recognize that the source of the data is a field w/ a length constraint and use that, but it apparently doesn't.

@TianxiangXiong - it is smart enough to recognise the source length - that's why you get 4096 not 32767, as that's the maximum substr can return from your original column, but multiplied by 4 to convert from char to byte.

You seem to be seeing a difference from the effects of character length semantics.
To avoid confusion with the maximum size allowed for the data type, I'm going to use 100 instead of 1024. If nls_char_semantics is set to byte then your first table is created with the column as 100 byte and that means both data_size and char_length are 100:
alter session set nls_length_semantics=byte

CREATE TABLE t (
    long_field VARCHAR2(100)
);

SELECT
    column_name,
    data_length,
    char_length,
    char_col_decl_length,
    char_used
FROM
    all_tab_cols
WHERE
    table_name = 'T';




COLUMN_NAME
DATA_LENGTH
CHAR_LENGTH
CHAR_COL_DECL_LENGTH
CHAR_USED




LONG_FIELD
100
100
100
B



When you create the second table using CTAS the data type has to be established as the table is created based on the possible values returned by the query. It isn't going to execute the query and find the longest actual value - but I don't think you're expecting it to, and it wouldn't work for empty tables if it did that. Instead it works out the longest possible result, as MT0 said, which in this case is 100.
But that is 100 characters. Based just on the column expression there is no way to know that is really limited to 100 bytes (by the base table definition), so the CTAS has to treat those 100 characters like any others; and as it's using byte semantics and a multibyte character set it has to allow for up to 400 bytes when it defines the new column.
And that means your second table is created with short_field defined as 400 byte:
CREATE TABLE t2
    AS
        SELECT
            substr(long_field, instr(long_field, 'c') + 1) short_field
        FROM
            t;

SELECT
    column_name,
    data_length,
    char_length,
    char_col_decl_length,
    char_used
FROM
    all_tab_cols
WHERE
    table_name = 'T2';




COLUMN_NAME
DATA_LENGTH
CHAR_LENGTH
CHAR_COL_DECL_LENGTH
CHAR_USED




SHORT_FIELD
400
400
400
B



fiddle
If you were using char semantics it would look more consistent:
alter session set nls_length_semantics=char

CREATE TABLE t (
    long_field VARCHAR2(100)
);

SELECT
    column_name,
    data_length,
    char_length,
    char_col_decl_length,
    char_used
FROM
    all_tab_cols
WHERE
    table_name = 'T';




COLUMN_NAME
DATA_LENGTH
CHAR_LENGTH
CHAR_COL_DECL_LENGTH
CHAR_USED




LONG_FIELD
400
100
400
C



Now char_length is still 100, but data_length is already 400, to allow for 100 multibyte characters.
The CTAS column expression still works out the maximum size as 100 characters, but now as it's using char semantics the second table is created with short_field defined as 100 char, so it looks exactly like the original:
CREATE TABLE t2
    AS
        SELECT
            substr(long_field, instr(long_field, 'c') + 1) short_field
        FROM
            t;

SELECT
    column_name,
    data_length,
    char_length,
    char_col_decl_length,
    char_used
FROM
    all_tab_cols
WHERE
    table_name = 'T2';




COLUMN_NAME
DATA_LENGTH
CHAR_LENGTH
CHAR_COL_DECL_LENGTH
CHAR_USED




SHORT_FIELD
400
100
400
C



fiddle
